# Why won't my prompt() run?

Tags: javascript

when loading the website i dont get prompted, this is for a practice at teamtreehouse and i cant see what im doing wrong can someone please explaine to me? thanks in advace

JAVASCRIPT

```
var firstName = prompt("Whats your first name?");
var lastName = prompt("whats your last name?");
var fullName = firstName.toUpperCase() + " " + lastName.toUpperCase();
var lengthOfFullName = fullName.length();
alert("The string" fullName "is" lengthOfFullName "long");
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Practice JavaScript Variables</title>

</head>
<body>
<script src="practice.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because your code contains syntax errors, so none of it runs.

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's console for errors? Debugging 101

Comment: You are missing the `+` operator in between your string concatenation..  `alert("The string" + fullName + "is" + lengthOfFullName + "long");`

Comment: (I'd disagree this is a typo, though; it's a fundamental misunderstanding of JavaScript syntax. Easily searchable, but not a typo. An ironic typo since it's done correctly in a previous statement :/ So... maybe a typo after all? Or mindless cut/paste?)

Comment: First you have to add + character before variable in alert statement then this code will not call anywhere in this way try to add function to call any where or add this in the body of your html not in external link in head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.length` is a property, not a function, so there are no
   parentheses.
2. You need to concatenate strings with `+`.

And using the wonderful snippet feature, we can actually run it:

```js
var firstName = prompt("Whats your first name?");
var lastName = prompt("whats your last name?");
var fullName = firstName.toUpperCase() + " " + lastName.toUpperCase();
var lengthOfFullName = fullName.length;
alert("The string " + fullName + " is " + lengthOfFullName + " long");
```

If you're using es6, you can use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var firstName = prompt("What's your first name?");
var lastName = prompt("What's your last name?");
var fullName = `${firstName.toUpperCase()} ${lastName.toUpperCase()}`;
alert(`The string ${fullName} is ${fullName.length} long`);
```

Or if you want to get *really crazy* with es6 expression interpolation:

```js
var fullName = `${prompt("What's your first name?").toUpperCase()} ${prompt("What's your last name?").toUpperCase()}`;
alert(`The string ${fullName} is ${fullName.length} long`);
```

(I wouldn't recommend you actually do this, but it's a useful demonstration of interpolating whole expressions.)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing several "+"s which need to be used to concatenate strings with variables in the last line which contains the alert statement.

Place a + symbol in between each variable and string.

For example:

`alert("The string " + fullName + " is " + lengthOfFullName + " long");`

Change this and see if it runs.